# Keep link to content even if private content

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

All my posts have a "group content visibility" field. So, when the content is private, if the user is not member of the group, the post will not be accessible.

In addition, if there is a link to this post, it will not be displayed in the menu for example. However, what I want is to keep this link even if the post is private. So, when the user clicks on the link, he will get a message like "you need to subscribe to the group to get access to that content".

For example, the website [drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me/series/organic-groups-drupal-7) is exactly doing that. If you click on non-free links, then you get a message to subsribe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: Drupal's menu system is based on permissions, if the user doesn't have access to a path the link will (rightly) not be displayed. If you want to change that behaviour you'll need to override how the menu system behaves in that respect. Probably not an easy thing to do, I'm not even sure how you'd approach it

Comment: The simplest approach I have found for menu items is to use the full URL instead of a relative path. This bypasses drupal permissions check